# rails 3 has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a legacy database. Users have many accounts, and Accounts have many users. There is a join table called UserAccountMapping:

```
=====================
|UserID  | AccountID|
=====================
```

Both columns are var chars types.

In Account.rb:

> has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :UserAccountMapping, :foreign_key => :AccountID, :association_foreign_key => :UserID

In User.rb:

> has_and_belongs_to_many :accounts, :join_table => 'UserAccountMapping', :foreign_key => :UserID, :association_foreign_key => :AccountID

Users also have a :email and :id column. The primary key for users is :id (which is an integer), and :email is a string.

When I do something like `User.first.accounts`, the WHERE clause of the join SQL will try to match UserAccountMapping.UserID to the :id of the user, but I want it to use the user's :email. Is this possible?

So, the SQL it generates is:

> SELECT "Account".* FROM "Account" INNER JOIN "UserAccountMapping" ON "Account"."AccountID" = "UserAccountMapping"."AccountID" WHERE "UserAccountMapping"."UserID" = 3

Instead, I want this:

> SELECT "Account".* FROM "Account" INNER JOIN "UserAccountMapping" ON "Account"."AccountID" = "UserAccountMapping"."AccountID" WHERE "UserAccountMapping"."UserID" = "user@something.com"

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Try setting the `User` primary key => :email

Answer (score 1):

The way you've structured the data here is so anti-Rails that you're going to have to fight to get it to work. That's the trouble with convention. If you run against the grain it gets very difficult to implement.

Using non-standard column names like `UserID` instead of `user_id` creates enormous amounts of complexity in your application. If possible, switch to the Rails style and save yourself all that trouble of having to over-ride everything.

You should also avoid using `has_and_belongs_to_many` as it's a relic from Rails 1 that isn't as useful as the `has_many :through` feature in Rails 2+. All you need is an `id` primary-key column in your join table and an associated model file that sets up the two `belongs_to` relationships.

Using a non-standard `id` column is also going to cause trouble and should only be done as a last resort. Most of the time you can work around this using a `UNIQUE` index on that column and the finder method for it:

```
@user = User.find_by_email(email)
@account = @user && @user.accounts.first
```

If you follow the "Rails way" things work a lot better. A good part of learning Rails is knowing when to play along and when and how to buck convention and go your own way without getting into trouble.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a legacy database, so I can't change the column names to follow rails convention. I've also tried the `has_many :through` feature, but I also have the same issue.

Comment: So, you should think about not using Rails, because it will be very hard and complex for you :(.

Comment: If you're really up against the wall, you might want to try using the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) ORM instead of ActiveRecord. It tends to be a lot more flexible as it doesn't make as many assumptions and can handle unconventional keying arrangements.